# Use date to update date

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to follow along to the exercises in [Beginning the Linux Command Line](http://amzn.com/1430218894). One of the exercises asks to set the current time to 1 minute ago.

While I can get the time one minute ahead:

```
echo $( date --date='60 seconds ago' )
```

I am unable to use it to set the time value.

```
date --set=$( date --date='60 seconds ago' )
```

I am assuming that I have to coerce the return of the macro to string using the same format that I will specify to the `--set` option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> -s, --set=STRING          set time described by STRING

A quote from `date --help`

You have to do `date --set='60 seconds ago'`

In bash scripting `'64 seconds ago'` is a string and `--set` takes STRING